# Excel Listbox in a Sheet with FreezePanes

Tags: excel, listbox, panes

I have an Listbox Multiselect ActiveX control in a Sheet with Freeze Panes. The problem is that when I try to select items the mouseover icon is the standard excel cross instead of the arrow. I know that this question was asked before, but I didn't find any answer.

Thank u in advanced for help

Comment: does the action change when you unfreeze panes? not sure what the link there is...

Comment: yes, with not freeze panes it work perfect

Answer (score 0):

I tested, and I came up with a few interesting observations.

1. In the ribbon, go to the developer tab. Make sure that the **Design
   Mode** is not on.
2. When I first froze panes on the sheet, the freeze line went through the listbox I created. This caused the behavior you are describing with the cross-hairs and being unable to select.
3. Then I moved the listbox. Still same problem. I tried clicking on various cells around the sheet and in the ribbon area, with no change in behavior.
4. When I clicked to another sheet and back again, it started working as expected. Normal pointer mouse. I could select multiple, and unselect as needed.

Based on what I've tried, it seems that making sure **Design Mode** is off, and clicking to another sheet and back again may fix the problem.